# Save d'alar'cop by Helping Him Defuse The Bomb Placed By An Assassin

Tags: password, chess

**[d'alar'cop](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2484/dalarcop)** was busy solving puzzles and making riddles at his home. He heard a knocking on the door. He got up and reached the door to answer the knocking. Once he opened the door, no one was there. He saw a packet lying in front of the door. It was addressed to cop. He took the packet and got back to his table.

d'alar'cop started unpacking the package with curiosity. As he removed the covering he saw a wooden box. He thought it would be some gift, from a fan. Once he opened the box, he saw a **letter**. Before opening the letter he also notices a **6 digit long LCD panel** and a **number pad with button 0-9 and an Enter** Key attached to the box cap.

d'alar'cop got confused, what is this? Is this some kind of a trick or something?

He took the letter in his hand and started reading it.

Here is the letter

---

Hi cop,

You don't know me. I don't have any problem with you personally either. One of your enemies hired me to kill you and I have already planted a bomb in your home. It may explode anytime. There is no way you can find it or defuse it (without my help).

I shouldn't have sent this to you if I haven't created an account at **[Puzzling.StackExchange.com](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)** today. I saw your profile and came to know that you are the most reputed user in **puzzling.SE**. I have also seen all the riddles and puzzles you made and the answers you posted. All of them are really brilliant and that made me think I should give you a chance to live, if you are really brilliant enough as I thought.

To defuse the bomb you have to enter a **6 digit code** with the attached number pad and the fun part is I am not going to tell you the code. I am just going to test you. If you are brilliant enough, you will get the code for sure.

Let's start with a **riddle**. I know you love riddles more than anything ;).

> I was made by hiring some from a family of twenty six
>  
>   And, if I count the twins as two, my total strength is six
>
> I will help you lit up your house
>  
>   And also to clean and tidy up your house
>
> But, don't try to get into me too much
>  
>   I will kill you with hypoxia and such
>
> My origin is actually from the Latin
>  
>   In perfect form, I am unable to be attained

Once you figure out all the six members, we can move to the next game. A game of chess. But you have to play according to MY RULES

**HERE IS THE GAME**

[image]

**RULES**

- Your pieces are White.
- Assign each member to the pieces you have respectively. That is, the
  White Pawn on the left is the first member, the next White Rook is
  the second member, the next White Queen is the third member and so
  on.
- I have already made all my moves and now it's your turn.
- You have to start from the left. That is, from the White Pawn
- You can only move your piece to the safe position.
- If there is no safe position, you can leave the piece unchanged.
- Also, you can cut my piece (Black). But, only if it's safe.
- You can only move a piece once and so the maximum number of moves
  allowed is six.
- You can make your moves one after another. You don't have to wait for
  my turn since as I told you, I have already made all my moves.

Now Start Playing.....

How was the game? Hope you enjoyed it. Otherwise, you will be **"BAAAANNGGGGG"**

---

Cop tried to open the door to run out, but it was locked. Someone might have locked the doors from outside as Cop took the parcel in.

Cop is currently working on it to solve it and save his life. Since he is a very valuable contributer of our community, it's our duty to help him. His loss will affect our community very badly for sure. So I request all fellow community members to help him figure out the code to defuse the bomb. Please post all your answers here. It will help him save himself. If Cop himself finds the answer, he will post the answer and how he saved himself here.

Since Cop is busy solving it, he asked me to post it here. If somebody post the correct code, I will inform him.

Comment: I confess, I hired the hit man (who just so happened to be http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/7313/zumer92) to do this. I was jealous of d'alar'cop's position and respect in the community, and due to his not-so-long-ago claims of giving me all his rep through bounties if he left, threatened to kill him. In hopes he'd start boy tying me and that I would reign supreme!

Comment: Qd7, Rg7, profit.

Comment: a single move is enough for check in the chess puzzle but i did not understand what it means

Comment: What grumpygutted bugger could downvote this brilliant question??

Comment: I don't understand the chess part.  We have to start from the white pawn, but there are no "safe moves" for it.  It is always threatened by the black rook.

Comment: @randalthor Me, I feel the chess part is poorly explained, i.e. what the actual objective is.

Comment: @McMagister - "If there is no safe position, you can leave the piece unchanged."

Comment: @No.7892142 - That's what makes it interesting.

Comment: @rand LOL I have to learn to read!

Comment: @randalthor I don't feel that way, I'm afraid. Gotta wait for the solution to give a final judgment of course.

Comment: @No.7892142 Not really satisfied with the riddle, I'm afraid.

Comment: @AeJey - d'alar'cop is saved! Phew :-)

Comment: And having helped him solve it, I can say this is a BRILLIANT puzzle :-)

Comment: Wow. At last  d'alar'cop got saved. Thank you all for helping him. :)

Comment: @McMagister helped cop in solving the riddle part and cop did the rest by himself. :) Excellent.

Comment: @No.7892142 Why did you direct that comment at yourself?

Comment: @pacoverflow Because the one I referred to was by me. Old twitter habit I suppose.

Comment: Hopefully cop realised that the front door was still working (because he opened it to get the parcel) and the first step would be to take the puzzle a safe distance outside and solve it there...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the riddle, [please refer to this excellent explanation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/6178/2484).

---

For the Chess part:

We assign the letters from VACUUM to the chess pieces..

The pieces are placed on: a2,Rb7,Qa1,e2,Kf4,Rg8.

Suitable new locations for them are: a2,Rb2, Qd7, e3, Kxf5,Rxg4

These new locations satisfy all the rules and result in a checkmate for Black with a safe King.

This gives a change vector of: $+0,-5,+6,+1,+1,-4$

So the letters from VACUUM would be transformed to: V V I V V I

If we turn this into Arabic numbers for the pad, we have:

$551551$ :D

Comment: Why not 554550?

Comment: @randalthor Any reason for using a greedy algorithm?

Comment: Both Rxg4 and Rg7 provide valid solutions!  d'alar'cop is still in danger!

Comment: @McMagister Actually Rxg4 will be better because it's not being attacked at all - which fits the rules. Thank you for your assistance, sir

Comment: @McMagister - No, you were right. Rg7++ is 'attacked' by the Black king (sort of). If Black gets 6 moves in a row after that, he could win. Rxg4 is still checkmate.

Comment: sorry @d'alar'cop - we were writing comments simultaneously there!

Comment: Next nitpick would obviously be instead of e3 going f3. Or actually moving to a3.

Comment: @No.7892142 e3/f3 wouldn't matter because it's still just moving up one.

Comment: @dalarcop Also one to the right. And a3 would actually matter in this case. And these are just the obvious variations, there might even be some more funky stuff in this position.

Comment: @No.7892142 - And the first pawn can't move to a2 or a3 because it would be *en prise* by the black rook.

Comment: @No.7892142 a3 or a4 would give W or X which would ruin the Roman numeral motif (since we need to keep under 6 digits). It's all a bit of fun. Take it easy :p

Comment: @randalthor Yeah, missed the rule to only move to safe positions on that one, I give you that. I was irritated by "can leave it be" on the rule next to that.

Comment: @dalarcop Yes, but I feel like the solution should be apparent in any case. You see, Rg7 also gives a solution that looks reasonable. 551551 is probably right, but it's not a real eureka solution, you know.

Comment: @No.7892142 Rg7 would technically be under attack. Rxg4 is not.

Comment: @dalarcop Depends on your definition of "safe", obviously.

Comment: @randalthor Congratulations on having a functioning memory, I suppose? Even though I hardly see it as an insult. In any case I don't see the relevance.

Comment: @No.7892142 - You don't see 'ridiculously childish' as an insult?! Agreed it's not relevant here; I just thought of it when I encountered you. No apology from you, I notice.

Comment: PHEW.. I am happy to know you are safe now. It's correct. :) and the bomb got defused.

Answer (score 12):

The first part would refer to

> Vacuum

I will help you lit up your house

> Light bulbs have vacuum inside

And also to clean and tidy up your house

> Vacuum cleaner

But, don't try to get into me too much
I will kill you with hypoxia and such

> If you are in a vacuum you will have no oxygen to breathe.

My origin is actually from the Latin

> Vacuum is originally a latin word

In perfect form, I am unable to be attained

> We cannot attain a perfect vacuum

Part 2

> 1. Rb2
>  2. Qd7
>  3. e3
>  4. Kxf5
>  5. Rg7 (protected from the Black King by the White Queen at d7)
>  or Rxg4 (the most correct answer as the Rook is not being attacked at all)

For the final answer that combines these two parts, please refer to this [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/6180/6178).

Comment: Huh, why not Rxg4?

Comment: Do we want to play, or do we want to win? :)

Comment: That's the question. If we want to win, we only need two of those pieces.

Comment: d'alar'cop is saved!! Wait a minute and he'll post up the answer :-)

Comment: Excellent. You found it out and with awesome explanation. +1

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer for the first part is:

> Power (the twins are double-U)

The hypoxia part:

> If you get electrocuted it can result in hypoxia?

Still thinking bout part 2

Comment: Your double-U helped me to realise what the right answer was, but McMagister beat me to it by seconds!

Answer (score 0):

The answer for the first part is

> Oxygen.

Fits the bill except for line 4, I suppose.

The second part doesn't make sense to me at all, though. I can assign the letters and then what. There's no real objective unless I'm missing something.

---

**Edit:**

Never mind, it doesn't make sense when I learn to lead. Hyperoxia != Hypoxia.

---

As for the second part:

> - Pawn Stays
>  - Rook goes to b2
>  - Queen goes to d7
>  - Pawn goes to e3
>  - King goes to f5
>  - Rook goes to g4

Now to get a proper cipher going with this.

Comment: Doesn't explain the twins though.

Comment: @McMagister Took that for a red herring. No twins (i.e. double letters), nothing to be counted twice.

Comment: How do lines 3 and 4 fit?

Comment: Line 3: No fire will burn without oxygen. Line 4: I recall oxygen being used in cleaning tools.

Comment: Oh, vacuum is also nice.